# Why they created a timeout

Tags: asp.net

if u add this to web.config, then if a page have gone through long process, the client will not have a timeout exception.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024000" executionTimeout="36000"/>
```

they are timing out things for a purpose, what is it?, I tried to create a website with two  pages I make a button in default1.aspx wait for 5 minutes. the other page requesting is not affected by that.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not 100% sure I follow you but the purpose of a timeout is to ensure a client does not wait indefinitely for a response that may not come, it is part and parcel of working in a stateless environment.

Answer (score 0):

So clients can't tie **precious server resources**...

Comment: Sure they can.  They'll just make another request.

Comment: a long process like upload a file, will do that regardless you like it or not, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

Request timeouts server-side are one thing, however IE and other browsers also have request timeouts.  If you're performing something costly server-side use a status area instead of Request-Response to deal with processing.